# Why do they only want loose cash and not bundles?

Tags: plot-explanation, hell-or-high-water

When they rob the bank in *Hell or High Water* they say:

> ... none of them in bundles, just the loose cash.

Why do they only want loose cash and not bundles? Why do they only steal small amounts of money at a time?

Answer (score 9):

Two reasons

Firstly, bundles of cash can contain *dye packs*....this is specifically mentioned in the movie (they are referred to as "ink packs".)

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dye_pack)

> A dye pack is a radio-controlled incendiary device used by some banks to foil a bank robbery by causing stolen cash to be permanently marked with dye shortly after a robbery.
>
> In most cases, a dye pack is placed in a hollowed-out space within a stack of banknotes, usually $10 or $20 bills. This stack of bills looks and feels similar to a real one, with technology allowing for the manufacturing of flexible dye packs which are difficult to detect by handling the stack.

[image]

<sup>Deployed dye-pack - (By Colin Brown from Silver Lake, CA, U.S.A - IMG_5096.JPG, CC BY 2.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=4322776)</sup>

---

Secondly, bill packs might contain **bait money** where the bill numbers are recorded making them significantly more traceable.

---

As for the amounts taken...they are limited to time and they can only grab what is in the teller's drawers and relatively low value bills at that (for the reasons stated). $100 bills are tracked I believe...at least that's indicated in the movie.

Also, stealing too much will draw the attention of the FBI rather than local law enforcement.

The head ranger believes they have a plan...

> "They're trying to raise a certain amount, that's my guess. It's gonna take a few banks to get there."

Comment: Yes the number is bill packs are mostly reason. Thats the reason in real time scenarios, bank robbers have to wait for few years before starting using that cash.

Comment: You didn't answer the second question "why small amounts..."

Comment: Much appreciated. Really a great film.